# What is this triangle system notification icon on Samsung Galaxy S9+?

Tags: samsung, system, notification-icons

What is this triangle system notification icon on Samsung Galaxy S9+? It appeared recently. And I can't even imagine what is it.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a **Data saver** icon.

> The icon is different from the data saver icon in stock Android.
>   Samsung started to use this data saver icon in Android Oreo update as
>   explained in this [guide](https://gadgetguideonline.com/s8/new-status-icons-in-android-oreo-update-for-galaxy-s8-and-s8/)

This Galaxy S9 status icon appears  if you enable data saver in Settings → Connections → Data usage →  Data saver.

[image]

*Data Saver status icon in Android Oreo update for Samsung*